# QuickBlox-android session reconnection

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

It has been observed that session does not reconnect even after adding connection listener. This is leading to a situation wherein mobile app stops receiving calls if there is a slight disruption in the network connectivity. Below is the code snippet from Android Studio. Please advise.

Below is the requested log (Verbose mode without any filter). The first three lines captured immediately after we switch off wi-fi. Ideally we would expect to see some reconnection activity kicking off but that did not happen. 4th line onwards are the statements captured immediately after we switched on the wi-fi and tried calling the other party. Thank you for you help!

Note: “MFSession is the log tag used by our app:

--- Log Start ----

```
06-07 01:44:58.555 26551-26551/in.medfone D/MFSession: Session Message= Wi-fi network is 
not available. Quality of video call may suffer
06-07 01:44:58.705 26551-26551/in.medfone D/ViewRootImpl: Buffer Count from app info with  
::-1 && -1 for :: in.medfone from View :: -1 DBQ Enabled ::false false
06-07 01:44:58.825 26551-27107/in.medfone D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  
[668x136]-format:1



06-07 01:45:07.475 26551-26551/in.medfone D/MFSession: Session Message= Wi-fi network is 
now available
06-07 01:45:07.530 26551-26551/in.medfone D/ViewRootImpl: Buffer Count from app info with  
::-1 && -1 for :: in.medfone from View :: -1 DBQ Enabled ::false false
06-07 01:45:07.625 26551-27107/in.medfone D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  
[499x104]-format:1
06-07 01:45:07.895 26551-26551/in.medfone D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
06-07 01:45:24.470 26551-26551/in.medfone D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
06-07 01:45:24.525 26551-13422/in.medfone D/MediaCodecVideo: SetAndroidObjects for surface 
decoding.
06-07 01:45:24.525 26551-13422/in.medfone D/MediaCodecVideo: NULL VideoDecoder EGL context 
- HW surface decoding is disabled.
06-07 01:45:24.530 26551-13422/in.medfone V/MediaCodecVideoEncoder: Found candidate encoder OMX.google.vp8.encoder
06-07 01:45:24.530 26551-13422/in.medfone V/MediaCodecVideoEncoder: Found candidate encoder 
OMX.Exynos.AVC.Encoder
06-07 01:45:24.530 26551-13422/in.medfone V/MediaCodecVideoEncoder: Found candidate encoder 
OMX.google.h264.encoder
06-07 01:45:24.530 26551-13422/in.medfone V/MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Found candidate decoder 
OMX.Exynos.vp8.dec
06-07 01:45:24.530 26551-13422/in.medfone V/MediaCodecVideoDecoder:    Color: 0x7f420888
06-07 01:45:24.530 26551-13422/in.medfone V/MediaCodecVideoDecoder:    Color: 0x15
06-07 01:45:24.530 26551-13422/in.medfone V/MediaCodecVideoDecoder:    Color: 0x13
06-07 01:45:24.530 26551-13422/in.medfone V/MediaCodecVideoDecoder:    Color: 0x7fc00002
06-07 01:45:24.530 26551-13422/in.medfone D/MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Found target decoder 
OMX.Exynos.vp8.dec. Color: 0x13
06-07 01:45:24.530 26551-13422/in.medfone D/MediaCodecVideo: VP8 HW Decoder supported.
06-07 01:45:24.530 26551-13422/in.medfone V/MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Found candidate decoder 
OMX.Exynos.avc.dec
06-07 01:45:24.530 26551-13422/in.medfone V/MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Found candidate decoder    
OMX.SEC.avc.sw.dec
06-07 01:45:24.530 26551-13422/in.medfone V/MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Found candidate decoder 
OMX.google.h264.decoder
06-07 01:45:24.545 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: AttachCurrentThreadIfNeeded
::ctor@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.545 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: Attaching thread to JVM
06-07 01:45:24.545 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: JVM::environment@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.545 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: JNIEnvironment::ctor@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.545 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioManager: ctor@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.545 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: JNIEnvironment::
RegisterNatives(org/webrtc/voiceengine/WebRtcAudioManager)
06-07 01:45:24.545 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: NativeRegistration::ctor@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.545 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: NativeRegistration::NewObject@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.545 26551-13424/in.medfone D/WebRtcAudioManager: ctor@[name=Thread-3328,
id=3328]
06-07 01:45:24.555 26551-26551/in.medfone D/ViewRootImpl: Buffer Count from app info with  
::-1 && -1 for :: in.medfone from View :: -1 DBQ Enabled ::false false
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioManager: OnCacheAudioParameters@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioManager: hardware_aec: 1
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioManager: low_latency_output: 0
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioManager: sample_rate: 48000
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioManager: channels: 1
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioManager: output_buffer_size: 3840
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioManager: input_buffer_size: 1920
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: GlobalRef::ctor@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioManager: JavaAudioManager::ctor@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioManager: IsLowLatencyPlayoutSupported()
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: AttachCurrentThreadIfNeeded
::ctor@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: JVM::environment@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: JNIEnvironment
::ctor@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioTrackJni: ctor@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: JNIEnvironment::RegisterNatives
(org/webrtc/voiceengine/WebRtcAudioTrack)
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: NativeRegistration::ctor@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: NativeRegistration::NewObject@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/WebRtcAudioTrack:
ctor@[name=Thread-3328, id=3328]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/WebRtcAudioTrack: Android SDK: 22, 
Release: 5.1.1, Brand: samsung, Device: hl3g, Id: LMY47X, 
Hardware: universal5260, Manufacturer: samsung, Model: SM-N750, Product: hl3gxx
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: GlobalRef::ctor@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: AttachCurrentThreadIfNeeded::
ctor@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: JVM::environment@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: JNIEnvironment::
ctor@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioRecordJni: ctor@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: JNIEnvironment::RegisterNatives
(org/webrtc/voiceengine/WebRtcAudioRecord)
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: NativeRegistration::ctor@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: NativeRegistration::NewObject@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/WebRtcAudioRecord: ctor@[name=Thread-3328, id=3328]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/JVM: GlobalRef::ctor@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioManager: SetActiveAudioLayer(5)@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioManager: delay_estimate_in_milliseconds: 150
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioTrackJni: AttachAudioBuffer@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioTrackJni: SetPlayoutSampleRate(48000)
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioTrackJni: SetPlayoutChannels(1)
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioRecordJni: AttachAudioBuffer
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioRecordJni: SetRecordingSampleRate(48000)
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioRecordJni: SetRecordingChannels(1)
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioRecordJni: total_delay_in_milliseconds: 150
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioManager: Init@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/WebRtcAudioManager: init@[name=Thread-3328, id=3328]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/WebRtcAudioManager: audio mode is: MODE_NORMAL
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioRecordJni: EnableBuiltInAEC@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.560 26551-13424/in.medfone D/WebRtcAudioRecord: EnableBuiltInAEC(true)
06-07 01:45:24.570 26551-13424/in.medfone D/AudioRecordJni: EnableBuiltInAEC@[tid=13424]
06-07 01:45:24.570 26551-13424/in.medfone D/WebRtcAudioRecord: EnableBuiltInAEC(true)
06-07 01:45:24.575 26551-26551/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: VideoRendererGui.setView
06-07 01:45:24.575 26551-26551/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: YuvImageRenderer.Create id: 0
06-07 01:45:24.580 26551-26551/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: VideoRendererGui.setView
06-07 01:45:24.580 26551-26551/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: YuvImageRenderer.Create id: 0
06-07 01:45:24.640 26551-27107/in.medfone D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [668x125]-format:1
06-07 01:45:24.670 26551-26551/in.medfone D/SRIB_DBQ: SurfaceView:updateWindow: viewRoot.sSVBufferCount=-1 mSVBufferCount=-1
06-07 01:45:24.670 26551-13433/in.medfone D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x8b00ea14
06-07 01:45:24.675 26551-13433/in.medfone D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [240x240]-format:2
06-07 01:45:24.675 26551-13433/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: VideoRendererGui.onSurfaceCreated
06-07 01:45:24.675 26551-13433/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: VideoRendererGui EGL Context: android.opengl.EGLContext@6803ed4f
06-07 01:45:24.715 26551-13433/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui:   YuvImageRenderer.createTextures 0 on GL thread:3329
06-07 01:45:24.720 26551-13433/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: VideoRendererGui.onSurfaceChanged: 240 x 240 
06-07 01:45:24.720 26551-13433/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: ID: 0. YuvImageRenderer.setScreenSize: 240 x 240
06-07 01:45:24.725 26551-26551/in.medfone D/SRIB_DBQ: SurfaceView:updateWindow: viewRoot.sSVBufferCount=-1 mSVBufferCount=-1
06-07 01:45:24.725 26551-13434/in.medfone D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x8b112a14
06-07 01:45:24.735 26551-13434/in.medfone D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [720x1124]-format:2
06-07 01:45:24.735 26551-13434/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: VideoRendererGui.onSurfaceCreated
06-07 01:45:24.735 26551-13434/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: VideoRendererGui EGL Context: android.opengl.EGLContext@79f679ce
06-07 01:45:24.785 26551-13434/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui:   YuvImageRenderer.createTextures 0 on GL thread:3330
06-07 01:45:24.785 26551-13434/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: VideoRendererGui.onSurfaceChanged: 720 x 1124 
06-07 01:45:24.785 26551-13434/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: ID: 0. YuvImageRenderer.setScreenSize: 720 x 1124
06-07 01:45:24.820 26551-13426/in.medfone D/VideoCapturerAndroid: VideoCapturerAndroid
06-07 01:45:24.820 26551-13426/in.medfone D/VideoCapturerAndroid: init: Camera 1, Facing front, Orientation 270
06-07 01:45:24.825 26551-13426/in.medfone D/VideoCapturerAndroid: Supported formats for camera 1: [
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 1920,
                                                                  "height": 1080,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 1440,
                                                                  "height": 1080,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 1280,
                                                                  "height": 960,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 1280,
                                                                  "height": 720,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 1056,
                                                                  "height": 864,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 1024,
                                                                  "height": 768,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 960,
                                                                  "height": 720,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 720,
                                                                  "height": 720,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 800,
                                                                  "height": 600,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 800,
                                                                  "height": 480,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 800,
                                                                  "height": 450,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 720,
                                                                  "height": 480,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 640,
                                                                  "height": 480,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                               },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 528,
                                                                  "height": 432,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 480,
                                                                  "height": 320,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 480,
                                                                  "height": 270,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 352,
                                                                  "height": 288,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                  "width": 320,
                                                                  "height": 240,
                                                                  "framerate": 30
                                                                }
                                                              ]
06-07 01:45:25.335 26551-13424/in.medfone D/VideoCapturerAndroid: startCapture requested: 640x480@30
06-07 01:45:25.335 26551-13444/in.medfone D/VideoCapturerAndroid: Opening camera 1
06-07 01:45:25.345 26551-13426/in.medfone D/AppRTCAudioManager: Android SDK: 22, Release: 5.1.1, Brand: samsung, Device: hl3g, Id: LMY47X, Hardware: universal5260, Manufacturer: samsung, Model: SM-N750, Product: hl3gxx
06-07 01:45:25.400 26551-13444/in.medfone D/VideoCapturerAndroid: Camera orientation: 270 .Device orientation: 0
06-07 01:45:25.405 26551-13444/in.medfone D/VideoCapturerAndroid: isVideoStabilizationSupported: true
06-07 01:45:25.405 26551-13444/in.medfone D/VideoCapturerAndroid: Start capturing: 640x480@[30000:30000]
06-07 01:45:25.410 26551-13444/in.medfone D/VideoCapturerAndroid: queueCameraBuffers enqued 3 buffers of size 460800.
06-07 01:45:25.505 26551-28550/in.medfone D/QBASDK: Can't parse the 'date_sent' value null: Invalid double: "null"
06-07 01:45:25.955 26551-13424/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: ID: 0. YuvImageRenderer.setSize: 480 x 640 rotation 0
06-07 01:45:25.960 26551-13424/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui:   YuvImageRenderer.setSize done.
06-07 01:45:25.965 26551-13433/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: ID: 0. AdjustTextureCoords. Display: 240.0 x 240.0. Video: 480 x 640. Rotation: 0. Mirror: true
06-07 01:45:25.965 26551-13433/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui:   Texture vertices: (-1.0,-1.0) - (1.0,1.0)
06-07 01:45:25.970 26551-13433/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui:   Texture UV: (0.0,0.125) - (1.0,0.875)
06-07 01:45:25.970 26551-13433/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui:   AdjustTextureCoords done
06-07 01:45:30.625 26551-13444/in.medfone D/VideoCapturerAndroid: Camera fps: 28. CaptureBuffers: 3.0. Pending buffers: []
06-07 01:45:35.485 26551-28550/in.medfone D/QBASDK: Can't parse the 'date_sent' value null: Invalid double: "null"
06-07 01:45:35.625 26551-13444/in.medfone D/VideoCapturerAndroid: Camera fps: 30. CaptureBuffers: 3.0. Pending buffers: []
06-07 01:45:35.900 26551-13433/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: ID: 0. Type: RENDERER_YUV. Frames received: 300. Dropped: 0. Rendered: 300
06-07 01:45:35.900 26551-13433/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: Duration: 9934 ms. FPS: 30.198616548669253
06-07 01:45:35.900 26551-13433/in.medfone D/VideoRendererGui: Draw time: 1869 us. Copy time: 1120 us
```

--- Log End ----

```
private QBChatService connectWithChatService(){
    //Create Session
    QBAuth.createSession(qbUser, new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(QBSession qbSession, Bundle bundle) {
          QBChatService.getInstance().addConnectionListener(connectionListener);
          currentQBSession=qbSession;
          login();
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
          currentQBSession=null;
          throwStatusMessages("Medfone Communication Hub Session Error - "+e.getMessage(), NotificationType.NOT_DEBUG_MESSAGE);
      }
    });
  return chatService;
}

private void login(){
  //Login to chat service
  chatService.login(qbUser, new QBEntityCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Object o, Bundle bundle) {
        QBChatService.getInstance().getMessageStatusesManager()
                .addMessageStatusListener(new QBMessageStatusListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void processMessageDelivered(String s, String s1, Integer integer) {
                        Log.d("MFSession", s+" Message delivered");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void processMessageRead(String s, String s1, Integer integer) {
                        Log.d("MFSession", s+" Message read");
                        if(textChatMessageStack.containsKey(s))
                            textChatMessageStack.remove(s);
                    }
                });
        try {
            token=BaseService.getBaseService().getToken();
            dateTokenExpiration=BaseService.getBaseService().getTokenExpirationDate();
            Log.d("MFSession", "Token= "+token);
            Log.d("MFSession", "DExp= "+dateTokenExpiration.toString());
        } catch (BaseServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            initQBRTCClient();
            throwStatusMessages("Successfully connected to Medfone communication hub", NotificationType.IS_DEBUG_MESSAGE);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
        throwStatusMessages("Medfone communication hub Login Error - "+e.getMessage(), NotificationType.NOT_DEBUG_MESSAGE);
    }
  });
}
```

and QBRTCClient:

```
private void initQBRTCClient() throws Exception{
    if(!isLoggedInToService){
        connectWithChatService();
    }
    rtcClient = QBRTCClient.getInstance(this);

    // Add signalling manager
    QBChatService.getInstance().getVideoChatWebRTCSignalingManager()
        .addSignalingManagerListener(new QBVideoChatSignalingManagerListener() {
            @Override
            public void signalingCreated(QBSignaling qbSignaling, boolean createdLocally) {
                if (!createdLocally) {
                    rtcClient.addSignaling((QBWebRTCSignaling) qbSignaling);
                }
            }
        });

    rtcClient.setCameraErrorHendler(new VideoCapturerAndroid.CameraErrorHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraError(final String s) {
        }
    });

    QBRTCConfig.setMaxOpponentsCount(1);
    QBRTCConfig.setDisconnectTime(30);
    QBRTCConfig.setAnswerTimeInterval(30l);
    QBRTCConfig.setDebugEnabled(false);
    QBRTCConfig.setDialingTimeInterval(10);

    //Set up Turn servers
    try{
        List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServerList = new LinkedList<>();
        iceServerList.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("turn:turn.quickblox.com:3478", "quickblox", "baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0"));
        iceServerList.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("turn:turnsingapore.quickblox.com:3478", "quickblox", "baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0"));
        iceServerList.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("turn:turnireland.quickblox.com:3478", "quickblox", "baccb97ba2d92d71e26eb9886da5f1e0"));
        QBRTCConfig.setIceServerList(iceServerList);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }

    rtcClient.addSessionCallbacksListener(this);
    rtcClient.prepareToProcessCalls();

    throwStatusMessages("Successfully connected to Medfone communication hub", NotificationType.IS_DEBUG_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: You mean that after network interruptions chat service is reconnecting well, but you don't receive any call requests then?

Comment: @IgorKhomenko, It has been observed that subsequent to a network disruption, app stops receiving calls. Even after setting the flag setReconnectionAllowed(true), we do not see connection re-establishing itself.

Comment: Can you post your Android log when reconnecting

Comment: @IgorKhomenko I have added requested log (edited questions - first code box). Let me know if there's anything else needed. Thank you!

Comment: Have you found a solution?